# Button content not updated with PropertyChanged Notifications

Tags: wpf, button, binding, inotifypropertychanged

What am simply trying to do is, when user click on the button, its content should change according to the coding. Here is the code. I have tried both, code behind way and XAML way of binding. but its not working.

```
<Button x:Name="Header" Content="{Binding listHeader}"  Click="HeaderClick"/>

private string listHeader;
public string ListHeader
{
    get { return listHeader; }
    set
    {
        listHeader = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("listHeader"));
        }
    }
}

public Calendar()
{
    this.selectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    this.ListHeader = selectedDate.ToString("MMMM");    
}

private void HeaderClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (StateOfList)
    {
        case StatesOfList.ListOfDates:
            {
                this.listHeader = selectedDate.Year.ToString();                    
                this.StateOfList = StatesOfList.ListOfMonths;
            }
            break;
        case StatesOfList.ListOfMonths:
            {

                this.FillList(ListDataTypes.Years);
                this.StateOfList = StatesOfList.ListOfYears;
            }
            break;
        case StatesOfList.ListOfYears:
            {

            }
            break;                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better bind your content with property name (ListHeader) and not the variable name(listHeader). So change these two lines in your code.

```
<Button x:Name="Header" Content="{Binding ListHeader}"  Click="HeaderClick"/>
```

and

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListHeader"));
```

Comment: The solution you gave is not working. I am totally surprised why its not working.

Comment: Make this change as well.
    this.ListHeader = selectedDate.Year.ToString();

Comment: Hey ! Everything is working correctly. I mean I tried to debugged it with visual studio and I have checked all e values of properties 10's of times. The value in <Button Content="{Binding ListHeader}"/> is also showing 2013 when I click on it. but I don't know why its not rendering.

Comment: I guess I written this in my answer to replace listHeader in your bindings with ListHeader.

Comment: Hey Nitesh, Please help me. If you want I can send you files. I don't know what is not working. Help me. Its not working.

Comment: It should work. You first implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel. Then bind your ViewModel with View. Do bindings for specific properties.

Comment: I hope you have not created this ListHeader property in your MainWindow code behind. If it is so, set DataContext = this in your Window constructor.

Comment: Not working. I think I should start from the scratch again. After the two days headache, I have to start again.

Comment: Hey ! I got that dude. Its working now. I used a timer to change the string value to check if the problem. Its changing. the problem was the PropertyChangedEventArgs("listHeader"). it should have been ListHeader. But I don't understand the reason and logic. I have also created OC which is called ListDB and implements INPC. I did the same PropertyChangedEventArgs("listDB");  and its working. Can you clearify this to me ?

Comment: In WPF databinding you need to bind to properties of your datacontext/itemssource. The way userlying framework understands the changes are through property notifications where you need to notify which bound property has changed by its (string) name. So when you want to notify that "ListHeader" property has changed you need to specify that name as string. Read this for further clarification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Comment: By OC you mean ObservableCollection that is notifying the changes (CollectionChanged) within the your collection i.e. add/remove/update of the item. However if you change the reference of your OC that will not be notified because the notification is for wrong property name. Read this for further clarification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx